# How to control the decimals in MaTeX

Tags: plotting, ticks, matex

I'm using MaTeX to display the ticks of a stream plot. However, I would like to standardize the number of decimals displayed in this plot, that is, I would like to show just one decimal. My code is the following:

```
texStyle = {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", FontSize -> 12};
m = 1.2;
graf = Show[
  StreamPlot[{If[u <= 0, -1, 1], u*w}, {u, -2, 2}, {w, -1, 1}, 
   StreamStyle -> Gray, 
   StreamScale -> {Automatic, 2, Automatic, 
     Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, Sqrt[x x + y y]]}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 2], 
  Graphics[{PointSize[0.015], Point[{u[3*M], 0}], Point[{-u[3*M], 0}],
     Point[{u[1/2 (4 M - CC M)], 0}]}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> BlackFrame, 
  FrameTicks -> {{With[{ticks = Range[-2, 2, .2]}, 
      Thread[{ticks, 
        MaTeX[ticks, "DisplayStyle" -> False, Magnification -> m]}]], 
     None}, {With[{ticks = Range[-2, 2, .5]}, 
      Thread[{ticks, 
        MaTeX[ticks, "DisplayStyle" -> False, Magnification -> m]}]], 
     None}}, FrameLabel -> 
   MaTeX[{"u/M", "M^{-1}(\\textrm{d}u/\\textrm{d}\\eta)^2"}, 
    Magnification -> m], BaseStyle -> texStyle]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't have MaTeX, but I think using `MaTeX[NumberForm[ticks, {Infinity, 1}], ..]` should do what you want.

Comment: If you show an example, please show a minimal and complete one (this one is neither). Carl is probably right, and this is not related to MaTeX—just use NumberForm.

Comment: I completed the code. I'm trying to control the number o decimals by using the NumberForm, however it does not work.

Comment: Following up on Carl Wolf's comment `With[{ticks=Range[-2,2,.2]},{#,MaTeX[NumberForm[#,{\[Infinity],1}],"DisplayStyle"->False,Magnification->m]}&/@ticks]` for the ticks works for me showing one decimal digit including "0".

Comment: Please, make an answer to this question with the suggestion, I would like to accept this! :)